# Configuring Master Slave config for MongoDB on single Ubuntu Machine

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, database

I want to setup Master Slave config for Mongo DB on my Ubuntu Machine. I can see the setting to do this in /etc/mongodb.conf but that would make my DB either Master or Slave.

Is there any way I can run two different server on same machine and use one as Master and other as slave. I want to do this for testing purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For testing purposes you can start both instances manually, take a look at [this link](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Master+Slave). Quoting from the docs:

> IMPORTANT
>   Replica sets replace master-slave replication for most use cases. If possible, use replica sets rather than master-slave replication for all new production deployments. This documentation remains to support legacy deployments and for archival purposes only.

Locate the folder where the MongoDB binaries are located:

```
mkdir -p ../master
./mongod --dbpath ../master --master --logpath ../master/master.log --port 27017
```

Then open up another terminal, navigate to the same folder and run this:

```
mkdir -p ../slave    
./mongod --dbpath ../slave --slave --logpath ../slave/slave.log --port 27018 --source=localhost:27017
```

Comment: Please include the linked info in the answer; the link can change or otherwise go down.

Answer (score 2):

The best way would be to not use /etc/init.d/* scripts and use the good old command line. Make sure mongodb is not running on your machine. Locate the folder where binaries are installed, and then from command line run:

`./mongod --dbpath /path_to_master_db_files --master --logpath /path_to_logs/master.log --port 27017 --fork`

Then open up another terminal, navigate to the same folder and run this:

`./mongod --dbpath /path_to_slave_db_files --slave --logpath /path_to_logs/slave.log --port 27018 --source=localhost:27017 --fork`

And there you go - you should have a master running on 27017, and slave running on 27018. Hope this helps.

BTW, I am assuming you are not running this configuration in production, and only want to try it out on your local instance.